# Two different HashSet objects affected by one command (JAVA)

Tags: hashset

I have a custom object:

Class(id, code, title, numberOfECTSPoints, headProfessor, attendingStudentsSet)

I create an instance of that custom object called class1, and use a pre-created HashSet to feed its constructor. After I do that and clear the HashSet which was used to create the object, the HashSet inside of the object gets cleared as well.

```
Set<Student> setStudents= new HashSet<Student>(); // this was fed with some Student objects

Class class1 = new Class(id, code, title, numberOfECTSPoints, headProfessor, attendingStudentsSet);

System.out.println(setStudents.size()); // 5
System.out.println(class1.getAttendingStudentsSet().size()); // 5
setStudents.clear();
System.out.println(setStudents.size()); // 0
System.out.println(class1.getAttendingStudentsSet().size()); // 0
```

I expected that the set inside of the created object would remain untouched by clearing the set which was used to feed the object's constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that they're NOT two different HashSets -- they're the same HashSet.  Every field or variable of class type is not really an object of that type -- its really just a reference to an object of that type, and when you assign it (or pass it to some method), you're really just passing a reference to the same underlying object, not copying the object.

If you want distinct objects, you need an explicit `new` or `clone()` in your code.  In your case, you could do

```
Class class1 = new Class(id, code, title, numberOfECTSPoints, headProfessor, setStudents->clone());
```

or you could put the `clone()` call into the `Class` constructor.

Comment: I got goosebumps from your answer. What the hell!! I had no idea it works like that. I need to test it to be sure, but as I believe I've grasped it I'll thank you immediately; Thank you! This is interesting af, somewhat mindblowing to me.